# Input variables use random values instead of the ones I want them to use

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

The inputs V, A and e inside the main function take on random values. Instead, I wanted to give them values through the inputs. I assume that it's because of the variables not being initialized in the graph function but these values come from structures. What did I do wrong?

Full code:

```
struct Edge {
    int src, dest, weight;
};

struct Graph {
    int V;
    int E;
    struct Edge* edge;
};

struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E)
{
    struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof *graph);
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;
    graph->edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(E * sizeof(struct Edge));
    return graph;
};

...

int main()
{
    int V = 0;
    int A = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int E = 0;
    int cidade = 0;
    int aeroporto = 0;
    int cidade1 = 0;
    int cidade2 = 0;
    int custo = 0;

    printf("Caso haja aeroportos, o vertice 0 e o ceu onde todos os aeroportos se ligam.\n");
    printf("Caso nao haja aeroportos, o vertice 0 e uma cidade.\n\n");
    printf("Introduza o numero de cidades: \n");
    scanf("%d", &V);
    printf("Introduza o numero de aeroportos: \n");
    scanf("%d", &A);
    printf("Introduza o numero de estradas: \n");
    scanf("%d", &e);
    printf("\n");

    E = A + e;

    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V, E);

    for (int i = 0; i < A; i++) {
        printf("Introduza a cidade e o custo de construcao do aeroporto: \n");
        scanf("%d %d", &cidade, &aeroporto);

        graph->edge[i].src = cidade;
        graph->edge[i].dest = 0; // vértice "céu"
        graph->edge[i].weight = aeroporto;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < e; j++) {
        printf("Introduza as cidades e o custo da estrada: \n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &cidade1, &cidade2, &custo);

        graph->edge[j].src = cidade1;
        graph->edge[j].dest = cidade2;
        graph->edge[j].weight = custo;
    }

    KruskalMST(graph);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem I think but I'll add to the code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don’t check that the scanf calls succeed.  You’ve no idea whether they are reading anything useful. You don’t print out the values as you read them.

Comment: It's the scanf calls themselves. They don't recognize the value I introduce.

Comment: Try to read with `scanf(" %d", &V);` <- put a space between `"` and `%d` do it for all your scanfs, maybe solve the problem

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Well i sugest to use step by step debuguing or put several printfs throw your code to verify where you lose that values

Comment: They are technically lost in the main function

Comment: Thank you, this has solved it. How can I fix this memory issue?

Comment: These are the only places I use memory allocation. So, maybe it's because of going beyond array boundaries